# How to deploy a node.js app into AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Am trying to deploy sample Nodejs application in AWS Elastic Beanstalk through AWS Console.My Nodejs application contains only HelloWorld message.
**My question is Am not getting Hello world Message when i click on Elastic Beanstalk URL**. I also checked logs but there is no error messages in Nodejs.logs and Error.logs.
**When I check that Elastic Beanstalk URL am getting "Connection Refused-due to Internal Server Error "** . Am creating Stack through Console by using JSON Template and my template contains Application,Application version, Environment and ConfigurationTemplate resourse type .My ConfigurationTemplate resourse type
contians the following OptionSettings as shown below-

```
"OptionSettings": [

                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
                        "OptionName": "MinSize",
                        "Value": "1"
                    },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:asg",
                        "OptionName": "MaxSize",
                        "Value": "2"
                    },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
                        "OptionName": "EC2KeyName",
                        "Value": { "Fn::FindInMap": [ "Environments",{"Ref": "EnvironUsed"},"InstanceKeyName" ]  }
                    },
                    {
                            "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
                            "OptionName": "IamInstanceProfile",
                            "Value": {"Fn::FindInMap": ["Environments",{"Ref": "EnvironUsed"},"IamRoleProfile"]}
                    },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
                        "OptionName": "InstanceType",
                        "Value": "t2.micro"
                    },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
                        "OptionName": "SecurityGroups",
                        "Value": { "Fn::FindInMap": [ "Environments",{"Ref": "EnvironUsed"},"BeanstalkSecurityGroup" ] }
                    },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
                        "OptionName": "VPCId",
                        "Value": { "Fn::FindInMap": ["Environments", {"Ref": "EnvironUsed"},"VPC" ]}
                    },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
                        "OptionName": "Subnets",
                        "Value": { "Fn::FindInMap": [ "Environments",{"Ref": "EnvironUsed"},"PrivateSubnet"]}
                     },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
                        "OptionName": "ELBSubnets",
                        "Value": { "Fn::FindInMap": [ "Environments", {"Ref": "EnvironUsed"}, "PrivateSubnet" ]}
                    },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
                        "OptionName": "ELBScheme",
                        "Value": "internal"
                    },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment",
                        "OptionName": "EnvironmentType",
                        "Value": "LoadBalanced"
                    },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:trigger",
                        "OptionName": "MeasureName",
                        "Value": "CPUUtilization"
                    },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:trigger",
                        "OptionName": "Unit",
                        "Value": "Percent"
                    },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:trigger",
                        "OptionName": "UpperThreshold",
                        "Value": "50"
                    },
                    {
                        "Namespace": "aws:autoscaling:trigger",
                        "OptionName": "LowerThreshold",
                        "Value": "49"
                    }
                ],
```

**and below is my Sample Nodejs Applicaton** -

```
var express = require('express');
var http=require('http');

var app = express();


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8081);


app.get('/',function(req,res){

 res.send('Hello World');

});


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

As am fresher to this AWS services ,Please Guide me How to solve this Error since I followed all instructions that given in AWS Documentation to create this Elastic Beanstalk to deploy application.

Comment: Please answer for this question.

Comment: I have problems with this too, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the connections on port 8081 (or whatever) are allowed by the security group

Comment: Sorry i didn't get your point .Can you please explain me clearly why Elastic beanstalk URL is not working .

Comment: The security group (in your case BeanstalkSecurityGroup) represent the rules that regulate network traffic, think to a sort of firewall. By default they are very restrictive, you probably have to allow connections on your port.

Comment: But am using Default security group where it allow all traffic and all port.The  problem here is servcie is not hitting when i click on Elastic beanstalk URL, since am not getting any errors in logs .Am not getting why service is not hitting here and EB URL takes long time to display message like - "internal server error- connection terminated ".please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: sorry, if it's not the security group, I don't know what could be.